# (Python) __new__ method returning something other than class instance

Tags: python

Is it possible, and if it is, then how to do so, that creating a new object of a class returns something other than the object itself?

Suppose, I want every newly created object to start out as a list consisting of itself.

```
>> class A:
      *magic*

>> a = A()
>> print a

[<__main__.A instance at 0x01234567>]
```

Probably it can be done by overriding the `__new__` method in some way, but how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `__new__` can return something else than the new instance:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        instance = super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        return [instance]
```

Demo:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
...         instance = super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
...         return [instance]
... 
>>> A()
[<__main__.A object at 0x10f33f390>]
```

Note that `__init__` is not called if the returned object is not the same type (so `isinstance(returned_value, A)` is `False`); that means that a custom `A.__init__()` is never going to be called here! Call it explicitly:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        instance = super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        if hasattr(cls, '__init__'):
            instance.__init__(*args, **kw)            
        return [instance]
```

Comment: What Python version is that? It doesn't work on Python 2.7.2.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: That was Python 3; updated to work on Python 2 as well; `__new__` only works for *new style* objects.

Comment: That works, but if the class contains `__init__` method as well, it is not called upon creating the object. How to make it work?

Comment: Right, `__init__` is called on the return value of `__new__`; you'd have to call it *explicitly* in `__new__` in that case.

Comment: Wait, wait, so class's __init__ will be called on the list? Testing shows that it will not, but how does Python tell if it's a valid return value to initialise?

Comment: @user2649762: ah, indeed, `type_call` will indeed double-check that the returned object is of the same type.