# Python __new__ dundor method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code below, I understand that `__new__` is used to create an instance of a class and the `__init__` method is used to initialize the values of the object.

Is `__init__` only called when you return an instance of the base class?

What I want is to return an instance of another class called class A.
Is there a way for `__init__` to configure the instance of class A?

```
# Python program to
# demonstrate __new__ method
  
# class whose object
# is returned
class GeeksforGeeks(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "GeeksforGeeks"
          
# class returning object
# of different class
class Geek(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        return GeeksforGeeks()
          
    def __init__(self):
        print("Inside init")
          
print(Geek())
Output:

GeeksforGeeks
```

Comment: Related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221858/python-new-method-returning-something-other-than-class-instance).

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` is invoked during object construction and it returns an
> instance or subclass of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()`
> method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is
> the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were
> passed to the object constructor.
>
> **If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.**

So no, it won't be called. You *could* manually call it yourself.